# Shell scripts, python, ld_library

Tags: python, bash, shell, dynamic-library

I've got a program that calls a shell script from python. In the shell script, I add to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH like so, pointing at the .so's from mdbtools.

```
NEWPATH=${PWD}"/mdbtools/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$NEWPATH
```

I'm pretty sure this part of the code is correct. I then call one of the programs from the .so, "mdb-export" like so, using variables from the input. :

```
mdb-export ${1} Athlete > "${2}athlete.csv"
```

Here's the confusing part. When I call the script from the commandline

```
./buildscvs abcd.mdb 1234
```

it works perfectly. The csvs are populated as expected. However, when I call the script from python:

```
    try:
        p = Popen([cmd, filename, prepend],  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True).communicate()[0]
        print "p", p
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

cmd, filename, and prepend are as follows

```
filename = /app/djangoFiles/meetPlanner/2011ROXBURY.mdb
cmd = /app/djangoFiles/meetPlanner/buildcsvs.sh
prepend = 824365891
```

The csvs come out blank. This seems consistent with what happens when you run a command with an unknown program name, like if I ran

```
abcd 1234.mdb > test.csv
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I'd very much appreciate any help you can give me

Thank you!

**EDIT**

After changing to 
    subprocess.check_call()

as suggested below, I now get the following error message:

```
/mdb-export: error while loading shared libraries: libmdb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting stdin and stdout to a pipe when you aren't using them? Just use `subprocess.check_call()` instead and any stdout and stderr should be printed, which will make debugging this vastly easier.

Comment: That helped -- thank you! Now I get this `/app/djangoFiles/meetPlanner/mdb-export: error while loading shared libraries: libmdb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This doesn't come up when I run it from the terminal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You must check not only `stdout` but `stderr` also.

```
(stdout, stderr) = Popen([cmd, filename, prepend],  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True).communicate()
if stderr != "":
    print stderr
```

Also you write that ou set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but where? In the script or in the python program? If in the python program you must pass the environment hash in the `Popen` call, but you don't do this.

The error that you get

```
/app/djangoFiles/meetPlanner/mdb-export: error while loading shared libraries: libmdb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

means exactly that that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set incorrectly (or is not set at all).

*update*

Ok, now we know that you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the script.
Don't forget to export it.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the script itself

Comment: do you export it? I mean in the script? it is possible that in the shell the variable is already exported ant that is why the script works, but in python script not yet

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions for how to debug how to set it correctly? It works when I call it from command line, but not from the python program

Comment: I don't export it, but would be happy to try. What do I need to do to export it?

Comment: Just add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the call of `mdb-export` in the script (to check the correctness of the idea).

Comment: Got it! Thank you -- my path was off